# Creating an Azure Storage Account in C# using Fluent API with no Allow Blob Public Access

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

My goal is to create an Azure storage account from C# code using the Fluent API (Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent).

My code executes correctly except that my organization has a policy which requires that all storage accounts must be created with "Allow Blob public access" set to Disabled.  Is there any way to specify that as an option using the Fluent approach?

```
                TargetStorageAccount = AzureClient.StorageAccounts.Define(storageAccountName)
                    .WithRegion(Region.AustraliaCentral)
                    .WithExistingResourceGroup(ResourceGroupName)
                    .WithSku(StorageAccountSkuType.Standard_LRS)
                    .WithGeneralPurposeAccountKindV2()
                    .Create();
```

Comment: i dont think Fluent has the option at the moment that you can use to create a storage account with "allow blob public access" disabled. Going with the Rest API is probably your best choice for now.

Comment: How's going? has your issue got solved ?

Comment: No, apparently the fluent API can't achieve the goal.  So, I punted back to using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.StorageManagementClient to programmatically create a storage account which prohibits creating public containers.  It's too bad as I'd rather use the fluent API but it is incomplete.

Comment: @Bonnie I have updated my answer. You can use ARM template and fluent API to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use ARM template to deploy storage account with "Allow Blob public access" set to Disabled.

For a fast demo, this is my template for the storage account:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storagePrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 3,
            "maxLength": 11
        },
        "storageSKU": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard_LRS",
                "Standard_GRS",
                "Standard_RAGRS",
                "Standard_ZRS",
                "Premium_LRS",
                "Premium_ZRS",
                "Standard_GZRS",
                "Standard_RAGZRS"
            ]
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        }
    },

    "variables": {
        "uniqueStorageName": "[concat(parameters('storagePrefix'), '4testonly')]"
    },
    "resources": [{
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "name": "[variables('uniqueStorageName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('storageSKU')]"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "properties": {
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                "allowBlobPublicAccess": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "result": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "done"
        }
    }
}
```

**allowBlobPublicAccess** set to false.

This is the code using fluent API to create this deployment:

```
    var storageAccountName = "<your new storage account name>";

    var templateJson = File.ReadAllText(@"<path of template file>\storageOnly.json");

    azure.Deployments.Define("storageDepolyTest")
            .WithExistingResourceGroup("<your resource group name>")
            .WithTemplate(templateJson)
            .WithParameters("{\"storagePrefix\":{\"value\":\""+ storageAccountName + "\"}}")
            .WithMode(DeploymentMode.Incremental)
            .Create();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the problem.  I can't create the storage account programmatically in the first place because there is a policy that prevents creating storage accounts which permit public containers.  So I can't programmatically create the storage account and then update it to not allow public containers via the fluent API.

Comment: @Bonnie, thanks for the tips,actually you can use fluent API to do that, I have updated my answer.

Comment: I appreciate all the work on that.  I think I'd like to point out that using an ARM template is a significantly more complex solution than using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.StorageManagementClient.

Comment: @Bonnie, got it, could you please accept it if this post is helpful? So that it will also help others have similar issue and close this question